# Xamarin or Xamarin.Forms for Android and classic Windows?

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms, exe

Is there a way to create a Xamarin or Xamarin.Forms solution that targets Android and *classic* Windows to produce a Windows 7,8,8.1,10 executable  (exe)?

I am not interested in UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms will support WPF in the future so you will be able to deploy an EXE file to those platforms. Read more about it here on the [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/glimpse-future-xamarin-forms-3-0/).

Also, you can always share the business logic, data and other layers with any other .NET application so having an Android app, Windows app and a core project that doesn't depend on Xamarin is perfectly fine.

You can already take a look at the WPF branch of the Xamarin.Forms project on [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/wpf/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF).

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. About the solution structure, are you suggesting 3 projects: business logic class library, xamarin android native and a wpf?

Comment: @dpant Yes, that's how I would probably do it.